# I have an object, call it Obj1 and need to compare values in Obj1 with another object obj2 'key-value' pair and return the keys if present

Tags: javascript, json

Consider below obj1 and obj2

```
const obj1 = 
{
  “array”:
 [{"path": "time.day"},
  {"path": “human.gender”},
  {“nestedArray”: [{"path": "time.Month"},{"path": "time.Day"}]}
 ]
}

const obj2 =
 {"time":{"day": "String”,"Month": “String”},“human”:{“gender”: “String”}}
```

Now I need to loop through array and nested Array in obj1 and check obj1 arrays 'path' matches with key-value pairs in obj2.how can this be done?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: An array, with common ones in both objects. like ['time','day','human','gender']

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```js
const obj1 = {
  array: [{
      path: "time.day"
    },
    {
      path: "human.gender"
    },
    {
      nestedArray: [{
          path: "time.Month"
        }, {
          path: "time.Day"
        },
        {
          nestedArray: [{
            path: "human.foo"
          }, ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const obj2 = {
  time: {
    day: "String",
    Month: "String"
  },
  human: {
    gender: "String",
    foo: "bar",
  }
}

const data = [];

function recursion(e) {
  if (e.path) {
    const values = e.path.split('.');
    const path = obj2[values[0]][values[1]]
    if (path) {
      data.push(values[0]);
      data.push(values[1]);
    }
  } else if (e.nestedArray) {
    e.nestedArray.forEach((element) => {
      recursion(element)
    });
  }
}


obj1.array.forEach((e) => {
  recursion(e)
});


console.log(data)
```

**IMPORTANT**

This code will work only if the conditions to add values to the array is when the **whole** path is correct - not just the part of it (and the path is composed of two parts)

Comment: TymoteuszLao this was great . How can we change the code so that it checks for n-number of nested arrays?

Comment: @Pablochocobar I updated my answer. Overall, what you need is the _recursion function_ which will trigger itself every time there is a nested array

Comment: this was very helpful. Dziękuję Ci !!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and check inside obj2.

```js
const obj1 = {
  array: [
    { path: "time.day" },
    { path: "human.gender" },
    { nestedArray: [{ path: "time.Month" }, { path: "time.Day" }] },
  ],
};

const obj2 = {
  time: { day: "String", Month: "String" },
  human: { gender: "String" },
};

const find = (arr, obj2) => {
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach((a) => {
    if (a?.path) {
      const [start, end] = a?.path?.split(".") ?? [];
      if (obj2[start]) {
        result.push(start);
        if (obj2[start][end]) result.push(end);
      }
    } else if (a?.nestedArray) {
      result.push(...find(a.nestedArray, obj2));
    }
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(find(obj1.array, obj2));
```

Comment: My apologies for not being clear earlier in question. We need to check the nested arrays and for n-number of nested arrays. which will have same format. Can you please suggest how can we ?